# asciidoc macros

Tags: asciidoc

I use asciidoc for rendering text.

I have difficulties to understand macros.
My goal is to have a simple macro processing (like in LaTeX).
I would like to write two Macros:

1. `FOO` should be replaced by `"bar"`
2. `MYTEXT(xyz)` should be replaced by: `"This is my text xyz!"`
   (perhaps with a different way to pass the parameter 'xyz')

Example file abc.txt:

```
text text text
FOO text FOO
text text text
MYTEXT(jajaja)
```

This should result in

```
text text text
bar text bar
text text text
This is my text jajaja!
```

I would expect that the definition of `FOO` and `MYTEXT` has to go into the file `abc.conf`; probabely into the secion [macro].

Additional question:

Are there problems with the pattern matching, if 
`FOO` should be replace with `'bar'` and `FOOX` with `'barbar'`?

Answer (score 6):

For the task of substituting FOO into bar and FOOX into barbar I would use the substitution syntax:

```
= AsciiDoc title
:FOO: bar
:FOOX: barbar

Regular text here using substitutions: {FOO} is bar and {FOOX} is barbar.
```

As you can see, you declare the substitution as `:VARIABLE:` and you use it as `{VARIABLE}`.

As to actually creating new macros, macros are usually of the type `macroname:content[Text input]`. They are documented [here](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#_macros) for the Python AsciiDoc project and eventually [here](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#macros) for the ruby based AsciiDoctor project but I have never really used them, I prefer substitutions and conditional blocks.

Comment: You provide an alternate solution, but you don't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate project, that I am associated with

http://github.com/verhas/jamal

which is a macroprocessor and it is available as an Asciidoctor preprocessor. Note that this is not Asciidoc, which is the format, but the implementation of the converter, Asciidoctor.

I think that Jamal just does exactly what you are looking for. It has complex macro processing capabilities that superseed those of Asciidoc and there are also a lot of built-in macros, some replacing, some extending the Asciidoc formatting and macro capabilities.