# Text substitution in AsciiDoc

Tags: asciidoc

I have an asciidoc document that uses a very technical and long term over and over again. It is very important that the term is written exactly like this. Now, I am looking for a possibility to use an acronym/shortcut instead while writing the document.
The shortcut text should then be expanded to a fixed value (best case a value that I can define elsewhere in the doc) while translating the document.

I read a lot about macros in asciidoc but did not yet find the right solution. Can anybody help and point me into the right direction?

Comment: After more research, I finally found the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045543/asciidoc-macros